# SailsJS: Setting autoPK:false still generates mongodb's id attribute

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

Using SailsJS, I'm trying to figure out how to use a custom Primary Key as Integer that auto increments.

For that, I passed `autoPK:false`, but I see that mongo still used it's 'id' field with UUID, as if Waterline is ignoring my *autoPK* entry.

For example, I define this model (configured for mongodb)

```
module.exports = {
  autoPK: false,
  attributes: {
    name:'string',
    personalId: {
      type: 'integer',
      autoIncrement:true,
      primaryKey: true
    }
  }
}
```

Here's an output from `sails console`:

```
sails> User.create({name:'Mike'}).exec(console.log)
undefined
sails> null { name: 'Mike',
  createdAt: Fri Mar 27 2015 22:11:51 GMT+0300 (IDT),
  updatedAt: Fri Mar 27 2015 22:11:51 GMT+0300 (IDT),
  id: '5515ab77ac1085260b221cfd' }
```

I would expect to see `personalId:1` or something like that instead of `id:'5515ab77ac1085260b221cfd'`.

Thanks.

Comment: I thought mongo *always* has an id field no matter what

Comment: @TravisWebb true, but sails maps keys/columns to it's own names (you can even specify using the `columnName` key for an attribute), notice how it's called "id" and not "_id", this output is from the `sails console` and not through the `mongo` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Mongo's auto increment in Sails can't be sequentially 1, 2, 3, etc. It will always be Mongo's `ObjectId`.
2. `id` field in Sails is necessary, since many convention still use it. Look after blueprint actions, actionUtil, etc.

So here is my solution, use this model configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  autoPK: false,
  attributes: {
    name:'string',
    id: {,
      autoIncrement:true,
      primaryKey: true,
      columnName: 'personalId'
    }
  }
}
```

It still not generate `personalId` as column name in Mongo, but it will use Mongo's default id convention which is `_id`. `personalId` will be generated if you switch your DB to another one like MySQL.

Comment: How exactly would you search anything with an ID both in mongo and mysql ?